# Angular Google maps (@agm/core) returns InvalidValueError

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am trying to use @agm/core to display Map components within my Angular Ionic application.

I have created a new component within my application that holds an `<agm-map>` tag and binds to the lattitude and longitude properties.

*map-update.component.ts*:

```
[...imports and component decl. ]
export class MapUpdateComponent implements OnInit , AfterViewInit{

  @ViewChild(AgmMap)
  public agmMap : AgmMap;

  @Input() lat;
  @Input() lng;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.agmMap.triggerResize();
  }

}
```

And the html file for that component is quite simple: *map-update.component.html*

```
<agm-map [lattitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [lattitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

This component is then created in a parent component whenever location data comes from the server. This parent component is called UpdateBox. This component has two helper functions to parse the location data (stored as JSON):
*updatebox.component.ts Edited for brevity*:

```
export class UpdateboxComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy , OnChanges{
  appointmentId: number;
  currentUpdates = new Array();
  currentUserID : number;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private userService : UserService,
    private photoViewer: PhotoViewer
  ) { }

  getLattitude(update : Update) : number {
    const coords = JSON.parse(update.updateSent);
    return parseFloat(coords.latt);
  }

  getLongitude(update : Update) : number {
    const coords = JSON.parse(update.updateSent);
    return parseFloat(coords.long);
  }

}
```

UpdateBox has an array of Updates `currentUpdates`, and that is where `UpdateMap` gets declared:
*updatebox.component.html*

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let update of currentUpdates">
[...]
<!-- Location-based Update -->
<div *ngIf="update.updateType == 4">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      Lat: {{getLattitude(update)}}, Long: {{getLongitude(update)}}
      <app-map-update lat="{{getLattitude(update)}}" lng="{{getLongitude(update)}}">
      </app-map-update>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

However, when I launch the application, I get an `InvalidValueError`:
`InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lng: not a number`

As far as I can tell the lat and lng should be numerical types since `getLattitude` and `getLongitude` both return `parseFloat`, but this clearly doesn't seem to be the case.

If I set the type of the Input variables lat and lng in `map-update.component.ts`, the error changes to `InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral with finite coordinates: in property lng: not a number`

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I'm pushing values onto a longlat array, when logging the values i'm pushing, it are numbers. when printing the final array. its all strings.